# are these xamarin packages essential for .net maui?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I was looking at my nuget packages and i noticed these xamarin packages.
Are these necessery? Can i delete them?

[image]

Comment: try it and you can report back here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update VS 2022. Create a new Maui project. Look at its nugets. You'll see those there, to support Maui on Android.

In the current nuget versions, the subtext is a bit more appropriate:

> .NET for Android (formerly Xamarin.Android) bindings for AndroidX library ...

That is, these are what support .NET running on Android platform.

Even if you are only targetting Windows currently, might as well leave them there. They won't be included in the Windows build.

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is at least one that is not needed. Navigation.UI 2.6.0.1 already contains Material 1.9.0.2. Legacy.Support.V4 is another I doubt you would need. Legacy is the right word there.

You can always just remove them one at a time, you'll soon find out if they are needed.

Comment: No and No. 1) Material is a "dependency" of Navigation.UI. That means when you install Navigation.UI, it ALSO installs Material. Removing Material would be a mistake. (Actually, it won't let you, since Navigation.UI requires it.) 2) An app will almost always include one version of Legacy.Support, in order to support older APIs. That library implements `AndroidX APIs` on ALL older versions (down to API 4). Given how new AndroidX is, that's a lot of versions that need some Legacy.Support.

Comment: *"in order to support older APIs"*: I meant to say "in order to support *devices* running older APIs. And I should clarify that it can't necessarily do exactly what the modern AndroidX APIs do, since those earlier Android versions lack needed functionality. The call works (does not crash), and the behavior does the best it can on that device.